# I Want to get specific data from Nsarray Contains NsDictionaries

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, nsdictionary

Hello friends i Am new in ios.in my App i am getting Json response from web service.response is type of Nsarray Contains NsDictionaries.in that dict there is categeryName=%@.i want to populate the table view which cantains only Names Of Product that matches with that Categoryname String.i am Getting All the Name From All the dict

```
     cell.textLabel.text = [[songArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Name"];
```

And this is My Array

```
value =     (
            {
        AreaBaseKey = "728b0e3e-295a-459d-9dca-56084afdeba8";
        CategoryKey = "9abcd7cb-6e4b-e311-93f5-001a640a73ee";
        CategoryName = Topuri;
        Code = 000000178242;
        IsActive = 1;
        Name = Chiloti;

    },
            {
        AreaBaseKey = "c666bd31-ac3c-4028-a983-51fb9063e0dc";
        CategoryKey = "9abcd7cb-6e4b-e311-93f5-001a640a73ee";
        CategoryName = Topuri;
        Code = 000000178242;
        IsActive = 1;
        Name = Chiloti;

    },
            {
        AreaBaseKey = "694c4b74-0a66-4f8d-b14c-8c53dfe8696f";
        CategoryKey = "9abcd7cb-6e4b-e311-93f5-001a640a73ee";
        CategoryName = Topuri;
        Code = 000000178242;
        IsActive = 1;
        Name = Chiloti;
               },
            {
        AreaBaseKey = "cd60fb89-8aae-4f02-925b-8e91ccd648b3";
        CategoryKey = "9abcd7cb-6e4b-e311-93f5-001a640a73ee";
        CategoryName = Topuri;
        Code = 000000178242;
        IsActive = 1;
        Name = Chiloti;
                },
            {
        AreaBaseKey = "54807449-9159-4701-9e72-d4cdf0e8163d";
        CategoryKey = "9abcd7cb-6e4b-e311-93f5-001a640a73ee";
        CategoryName = Topuri;
        Code = 000000178242;
        IsActive = 1;
        Name = Chiloti;
                },
            {
        AreaBaseKey = "1ec28a54-c0d1-4f99-966d-02f83ece35d2";
        CategoryKey = "9abcd7cb-6e4b-e311-93f5-001a640a73ee";
        CategoryName = Topuri;
        Code = 000000178242;
        IsActive = 1;
        Name = Chiloti;
                },
            {
        AreaBaseKey = "996cb68e-f950-e311-93f8-001a640a73ee";
        CategoryKey = "9abcd7cb-6e4b-e311-93f5-001a640a73ee";
        CategoryName = Topuri;
        Code = 000000178242;
        IsActive = 1;
        Name = Chiloti;
                },
            {
        AreaBaseKey = "a6dac1ba-744b-e311-93f5-001a640a73ee";
        CategoryKey = "9abcd7cb-6e4b-e311-93f5-001a640a73ee";
        CategoryName = Topuri;
        Code = 000000178242;
        IsActive = 1;
        Name = Chiloti;
              },
            {
        AreaBaseKey = "8c36f9e0-744b-e311-93f5-001a640a73ee";
        CategoryKey = "9abcd7cb-6e4b-e311-93f5-001a640a73ee";
        CategoryName = Topuri;
        Code = 000000178242;
        IsActive = 1;
        Name = Chiloti;
               },
            {
        AreaBaseKey = "ec0c9f6b-754b-e311-93f5-001a640a73ee";
        CategoryKey = "9abcd7cb-6e4b-e311-93f5-001a640a73ee";
        CategoryName = Topuri;
        Code = 000000178242;
        IsActive = 1;
        Name = Chiloti;

    },
            {
        AreaBaseKey = "1a96ca82-a2f1-48d2-91c3-a14ae3d09f70";
        CategoryKey = "8cbcd7cb-6e4b-e311-93f5-001a640a73ee";
        CategoryName = Pachete;
        Code = 100;
        IsActive = 0;
        Name = 3pizza;
                },
```

)

**I Am Doing this**

```
{   NSString *str = self.AppDelegate.indexname;
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY CategoryName LIKE %@",str];
    NSArray *result = [songArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    NSLog(@"%@",result);
}
```

**And This Also**

```
{
 NSString *str=self.AppDelegate.indexname;
 NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for(NSDictionary *dict in songArray)
 {
        if([[dict objectForKey:@"CategoryName"]isEqualToString:str])
    {
        [arr addObject:dict];
        NSLog(@"%@",arr);
    }
 }
```

}

But Not Getting Output I want at this is the Errror in line NSArray *result = [songArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

Comment: Is there Any parsing Method That Can Help to parse only Required item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NSPredicate` for filter `NSArray` or `NSMutableArray` of `NSDictionary` or `NSMutableDictionary`.

```
NSString *str = <search string>;
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY CategoryName LIKE %@", str];
NSArray *result = [value filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

To know about more `NSPredicate` checkout that link - [How To Create Predicates](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pCreating.html)

Comment: What is the value in that .is it stored Array Or What.i am Getting Error -undeclared

Comment: When I Am Doing This NSString *str = [self.AppDelegate.indexname string];   GettingError

Comment: what is indexname? is it array or string?

Comment: It is String.indexname is used to Store cell.text Which is  CategoryName.

Comment: if its string then simply use NSString *str = self.AppDelegate.indexname;

Comment: songArray is mutableArray

Comment: you have to simply pass search string if you will pass "Topuri" in str then it will filter all result matched to that string.

Comment: thank bro i done it for any other who wants to know more https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xf5QDG5Y2TU use this link

Answer (score 0):

Then you have to filter first the songArray for those dictionaries where your "CategoryName" and "Name" matches, and store it in another array. Then use that array in your dataSource methods.

Here's how you can do that, (Add the below code after you parse your JSON response)

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutableArray new];
for(NSDictionary *dict in songArray) {

if(dict@[CategoryName] == dict@[Name]) 
[arr addObject:dict];
```

}

Now use your array "arr" in your tableView datasource methods (i.e in numberOfRowsInSection: and cellForRowAtIndexPath: methods).

Comment: Thank For Helping Me Bro.Bro I Am Getting Loop Of same Dict.i want to match "SomeString" with "CategoryName" if They Match then I want to Store "Name" value of that Dict and show it on TableView

Comment: Don't compare NSStrings using ==. That operator is for primitive values, not objects.

Comment: like the "Topuri" is the CategoryName then Name on That Dict i Want on TableView

Comment: i used isEqualToString

Comment: Yes isEqualToString should be used. I forgot. So you get it working or any more help required ?

Comment: No.I Am Getting Loop Of Same Dict

Comment: That's weird. Edit your question with some code where you're trying to filter the data. That would give us more clarity so we can help.

Comment: I Am not Filtering the Data

Comment: Then what you are returning in your numberOfRowsInSection: method ?

Comment: Show me Some Code That Can Traverse through All Dict and Compare ObjectForKey"CategoryName" with "SomeString" if They Are Equal Add that string to Array Finally i Can Display Array That Store All Name In It

Comment: Then I think @abhishekkharwar and me already provided you the code in our answers.

Comment: i Edit my Question And i am tring both type.but its not Working